# guard-rspec not detecting changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

I am very new to RoR, following the Ruby Tutorial by Michael Hartly and after setting up guard-rspec, it does not detect changes to files that are being watched. I've searched around extensively and (unless I am not understanding something - which is all too possible) non of the answers apply to me. Everything else seems to work.

I am running Windows 8 and have it setup so it should show test results in Sublime Text 2. I get 2 notifications when starting Guard showing RSpec results of all my tests, but that seems to be the last I see of it. I can run all the tests, but it does not run when changing a watched file.

The files I am changing are in C:\Sites\demo\app\views\static_pages with \demo being the root of my rails app.

I have attached my Gemfile and Guardfile below. If there is something else needed to solve this please let me know. I hope I didnt give too much or too little info but I am really wet behind the ears! Thanks!

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'listen'

end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

# Test gems on Windows
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fchange', '0.0.5'
  gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  gem 'win32console', '1.3.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Guardfile:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

guard 'spork', :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')
  watch('spec/support/')
end

    guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false, :cli => '--drb' do


      watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
      watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
      watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }


        # Rails example
      watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
      watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
      watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
      watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
      watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
      watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

      # Capybara request specs
      watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

      watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
          ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
          "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
          "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
          (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
          "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
        end
      watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
          (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
          "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
        end
     end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

Comment: If you change a file in `spec/support` do your specs rerun?

Comment: I have no such file... Am I supposed to?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. What about a controller? Will any file changecause guard to update?

Comment: Since you are just starting out, I would not worry about guard. Just run the tests yourself. You could set up spork to make them faster but doing it manually helps you learn. Then later down the road you can optimize your workflow when you understand everything better. Just my advice on starting out. Good luck

Comment: can you post your `spec_helper.rb` file? It should be in `spec/spec_helper.rb`

Comment: @JasonTruluck I updated the question with spec_helper.rb

Comment: @fontno thanks! I just hate when things don't work. If I hadn't bothered originally I would have been fine. But cant just leave it not working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766511/tests-do-not-run-when-file-changes-with-guard-and-rspec-on-windows.

Comment: @JasonTruluck I understand, Im the same way. I have just learned from experience that the rails ecosystem is large and there is a tendency to want to learn everything at once, when the rewards are greater to focus on the core. Hope you get it working. cheers

Comment: @JimStewart you are correct... I did search around for a while but I suppose part of learning to program is learning to navigate stackoverflow. And thanks! That solved my issue and we are good to go!!